# Pandas get new column from rows of multiple columns (where entries are lists)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dictionary that I would like to turn into a dataframe and then combine *some* of the columns of that dataframe into one column.

my dictionary looks like this:

```
mydict = {'Participants': {'source': ['1', '2', '3'],
                           'name': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
                           'Entry (1)': ['Address1', 'Address2', 'Address3'],
                           'Entry (2)': ['Number1', 'Number2', 'Number2'],
                           'Entry (3)': ['Start1', 'Start2', 'Start3']},
            'Countries': {'DK': ['1', '2', '3'],
                      'UK': ['1', '3', '2'],
                      'CDN': ['3', '2', '1'],
                      'FR': ['1', '2', '3']}}
```

and the resulting dataframe looks like this:
 `df = pd.DataFrame(mydict)`

df:

```
           Countries                    Participants
CDN        [3, 2, 1]                             NaN
DK         [1, 2, 3]                             NaN
Entry (1)        NaN  [Address1, Address2, Address3]
Entry (2)        NaN     [Number1, Number2, Number2]
Entry (3)        NaN        [Start1, Start2, Start3]
FR         [1, 2, 3]                             NaN
UK         [1, 3, 2]                             NaN
name             NaN                       [A, B, C]
source           NaN                       [1, 2, 3]
```

I have multiple "Entry (n)" columns which contain "Address, Number and Start" info for every participant (`df['Participants']['name']`).
What I need now is an additional column "Entries" which combines for every row the info of `Entry (1)`, `Entry (2)` and `Entry(3)`. As the number of Entries (`Entry (n)` varies from data source to data source, I need to get the number of entries like this:

`entries = re.findall(r'Entry \(\d\)', str(mydict['Participants'].keys()))`

Which leaves me with a list of all entries: `['Entry (1)', 'Entry (2)', 'Entry (3)']`.

What I would like to have at the end is a dataframe like this:

```
           Countries                    Participants
CDN        [3, 2, 1]                             NaN
DK         [1, 2, 3]                             NaN
Entry (1)        NaN  [Address1, Address2, Address3]
Entry (2)        NaN  [Number1, Number2, Number2]
Entry (3)        NaN  [Start1, Start2, Start3]
Entries          Nan  ['Address1\nNumber1\Start1', 'Address2\nNumber2\Start2', 'Address3\nNumber3\nStart3']  <<-- I need this
FR         [1, 2, 3]                             NaN
UK         [1, 3, 2]                             NaN
name             NaN                       [A, B, C]
source           NaN                       [1, 2, 3]
```

Could anyone please tell me a pandas specific way of how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you need

```
s=pd.DataFrame(df.filter(like='Entry',axis=0).Participants.tolist()).apply('/n'.join).tolist()
df.loc['Entries','Participants']=s
df
Out[64]: 
                                                Participants  Countries
CDN                                                      NaN  [3, 2, 1]
DK                                                       NaN  [1, 2, 3]
Entry (1)                     [Address1, Address2, Address3]        NaN
Entry (2)                        [Number1, Number2, Number2]        NaN
Entry (3)                           [Start1, Start2, Start3]        NaN
FR                                                       NaN  [1, 2, 3]
UK                                                       NaN  [1, 3, 2]
name                                               [A, B, C]        NaN
source                                             [1, 2, 3]        NaN
Entries    [Address1/nNumber1/nStart1, Address2/nNumber2/...        NaN
```

Notice you can add `sort_index` at the end

Comment: Now... Why didn't I think to use `filter`?   That's smart.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try this:

<strike>df.at['Entries','Participants'] = ['\n'.join(i) for i in (zip(*df.loc[['Entry (1)','Entry (2)','Entry (3)'],'Participants']))]</strike>

Borrowed from @W-B solution using filter instead of list of indexes:

```
df.at['Entries','Participants'] = ['\n'.join(i) for i in (zip(*df.filter(like='Entry', axis=0)['Participants']))]
df.sort_index()
```

Output:

```
                                                Participants  Countries
CDN                                                      NaN  [3, 2, 1]
DK                                                       NaN  [1, 2, 3]
Entries    [Address1\nNumber1\nStart1, Address2\nNumber2\...        NaN
Entry (1)                     [Address1, Address2, Address3]        NaN
Entry (2)                        [Number1, Number2, Number2]        NaN
Entry (3)                           [Start1, Start2, Start3]        NaN
FR                                                       NaN  [1, 2, 3]
UK                                                       NaN  [1, 3, 2]
name                                               [A, B, C]        NaN
source                                             [1, 2, 3]        NaN
```